# Comparing timestamps within margin in R

Tags: r, timestamp, time-series

I am trying to find common timestamps between two dataframes. There is a small difference between them which can vary by upto 1 min. The final aim is to get the index number of *t1* that matches with *t2*.

One of the approaches I attempted is below:

```
t1<-c("2019-12-02 12:40:38", "2019-12-02 12:41:42", "2019-12-18 08:50:59", "2019-12-18 10:27:35", "2019-12-18 10:31:37", "2019-12-18 13:11:57")
 
t2<-c("2019-12-02 12:39:57", "2019-12-02 12:40:34", "2019-12-02 13:16:10", "2019-12-02 14:08:23", "2019-12-18 10:26:17", "2019-12-18 10:31:58", "2019-12-18 13:10:45")

t1<-as.POSIXct(strptime(t1, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M"))
t2<-as.POSIXct(strptime(t2, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M"))

common_time<-format(anytime(intersect(t1,t2)), "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")
```

I have also tried rounding to the nearest minute (using *round_date(1 minutes)*), which misses some values (e.g. 12:41:42 and 12:40:34). My questions are:

i) From the above how can I get all the index numbers of *t1* that matches *t2*?
ii) Is there a better approach to this?

In general T2 will have less elements than T1. Link to full datasets are below:

T1: https://www.dropbox.com/s/7nhxdvhbrhkb6rt/file_modified_times.csv?dl=0

T2: https://www.dropbox.com/s/nm72na37u0dkzil/OS_times.csv?dl=0

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `c(na.omit(match(t1,t2)))`  works? or `c(na.omit(match(t2,t1)))` ...

Comment: Does not work as it found 0 matches. Output is "integer(0)"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `nearest`from `data.table`:

```
t1<-c("2019-12-02 12:40:38", "2019-12-02 12:41:42", "2019-12-18 08:50:59", "2019-12-18 10:27:35", "2019-12-18 10:31:37", "2019-12-18 13:11:57")

t2<-c("2019-12-02 12:39:57", "2019-12-02 12:40:34", "2019-12-02 13:16:10", "2019-12-02 14:08:23", "2019-12-18 10:26:17", "2019-12-18 10:31:58", "2019-12-18 13:10:45")

T1<-as.POSIXct(t1)
T2<-as.POSIXct(t2)


T1 <- data.table(t1 = T1)
T2 <- data.table(t2 = T2)

T1[T2,roll='nearest',.(x.t1,t2,dt=difftime(t2,x.t1)),on=.(t1==t2),allow.cartesian=T]

                  x.t1                  t2        dt
1: 2019-12-02 12:40:38 2019-12-02 12:39:57  -41 secs
2: 2019-12-02 12:40:38 2019-12-02 12:40:34   -4 secs
3: 2019-12-02 12:41:42 2019-12-02 13:16:10 2068 secs
4: 2019-12-02 12:41:42 2019-12-02 14:08:23 5201 secs
5: 2019-12-18 10:27:35 2019-12-18 10:26:17  -78 secs
6: 2019-12-18 10:31:37 2019-12-18 10:31:58   21 secs
7: 2019-12-18 13:11:57 2019-12-18 13:10:45  -72 secs
```

Comment: no quite, the first row of t1 is matched to the two first rows of t2. However, this only works in one direction : if t1>t2 it looks forward instead of backward. This problem is occuring for rows 3 & 4. Struggling to find a workaround.

Comment: Hi Waldi, I had actually deleted my original comment about mismatching df lengths. So the answer that you have provided is correct. Finally, how would you recommend to get the index number of the matched elements?

Comment: you can add Id to each table with following commands : 
T1[,id1:=seq_len(.N)]
T2[,id2=seq_len(.N)] and then add id1 and id2 to the list of results. Still surprised by rows 3&4